# Express Σ+ as Regex

Tags: regex, concatenation, computer-science, alphabet

How do I express Σ+ as a regular expression by using Σ and Σ*.

Answer (score 3):

Since Σ+ means "one or more occurrences of Σ" and Σ* means "zero or more occurences of Σ", you can replace Σ+ with ΣΣ*